# построить кусочно-линейную функцию

Tags: python

Полностью задача звучит так: построить функцию f(x), которая определенна на [a,b] и в некоторых точках принимает значения f(xi)=yi. Я понимаю, что мне нужно написать кусочно-линейную функцию, которая будет выдавать значения y, но как это сделать - вопрос открытый...
Пока есть только это:

```
x = []
y = []

def f(x,y):
    for i in range(100):
     for x[i] in range(i):
       return y[i]
```

Comment: причем тут питон? откуда берутся некоторые точки xi и yi, а так же a и b?

Comment: в этом и проблема - точки и промежуток не заданы, а просто говорится, что они есть

Comment: Если по условию задачи, функция определена на отрезке [a, b], то значит там каждому значению абсцисс, есть значение ординат. Это просто вы берете и строите. Можно ли использовать готовую библиотеку matplotlib, это упрощает вам все.
ваше определение функции неверное! Ерунда...  где у вас описание, что есть функция y(x), как ваша функция f будет это считать?

Answer (score 1):

Например, так - создаёте списки `X`-координат по возрастанию и `Y`-координат (в соотв. порядке).

При вызове функции с координатой `x` ищете линейным поиском, если точек немного, или бинарным, если много, соответствующий интервал и выдаёте линейную интерполяцию `y` для данного `x`

```
y = y[i] + (x - x[i])*(y[i+1]-y[i])/(x[i+1]-x[i])
```